# Fix axios response type being any

Tags: typescript, axios, react-query

This is my basically my code (I copied stuff together that sits in different files):

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';

interface Scenario {
    id: number,
    name: string
}

const scenario = {
    getAll: () => axios.get<Scenario[]>(`/api/dyn/ax_scenario`)
}

const { 
    isLoading,
    isErrors,
    data = []
} = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['api.scenario.getAll'],
    queryFn: api.scenario.getAll
});
```

When I hover over data I get this Typescript information:

```
const data: any[] | AxiosResponse<Scenario[], any>
```

Why is there `any[]`?

I want the response to just be `AxiosResponse<Scenario[]>`

Answer (score 1):

The type of `data` as provided by `useQuery` is the return type of `queryFn` or `undefined`, in your case `AxiosResponse<Scenario[], any> | undefined`.

In addition to this you give `data` a default value by `data = []`, and since TypeScript doesn't know the type of `[]` it gives it the type `any[]`, so you get `AxiosResponse<Scenario[], any> | any[]`.

If you wish to provide another (e.g. more strictly typed) default type for `data`, you can do that. But from `useQuery` you will always get `undefined`. To provide a type for the default empty array you can do a type assertion by `data = [] as Scenario[]`.

Comment: I basically just want data to be some sort of array, either an empty one (hence the data = []) or one of type Scenario[]

because I have the problem I cannot do data.find() further down below in the code because Typescript says: The property "find" does not exist for the type "AxiosResponse<Scenario[], any>".ts(2339)

Comment: I just noticed, if I do this all is fine but this is so cubersome????

axios.get<Scenario[]>(`/api/dyn/ax_scenario`).then((response: AxiosResponse<Scenario[]>) => response.data)

Comment: I updated my answer on how to get a stricter type for `[]`. `.then(((response) => response.data)` is what  you need to do to get the `data` property of `AxiosResponse`. I wouldn't call that cumbersome.